# Google analytics not sending custom dimensions with pageview hits

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, custom-dimensions

I'm using google analytics to track page views on my site. trying to send custom dimensions during my pageviews. Here is what I have for the JS code

```
ga("create", '<UA-tracking ID goes here-01>', {
                'name': 'TrackingID3'
            });

                // SendPageView
                ga(function () {
                    var trackers = ga.getAll();
                    trackers.forEach(function (tracker) {

                        ga('set', 'dimension1', '187989840'); // departmentId
                        ga('set', 'dimension2', 'BLUE JEANS'); // caseName
                        tracker.send("pageview");
                    });
                });
```

The code above works but it does not send the custom dimensions

[image: non-working live project]

I made a new web project and a new google analytics account (new email). Everything is set up and working in the new google analytics account. Here is the code i have for the second web project

```
ga('create', 'UA-tracking ID goes here-01', {
        'cookieDomain': 'none'
    });

    // SendPageView
    ga(function () {
        var trackers = ga.getAll();
        trackers.forEach(function (tracker) {

            var dimensionValue = '187989840'; // departmentId
            ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);

            var dimensionValue = 'BLUE JEANS'; // caseName
            ga('set', 'dimension2', dimensionValue);

            tracker.send("pageview");
        });
    });
```

I tested the new web project and it successfully send the custom dimensions
[image: working example]

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a collision of using `ga('set',...)` command and tracker name parameter in the `ga('create', ...)` command.
To avoid this you might want to use specific tracked method:

```
trackers.forEach(function (tracker) {

            var dimensionValue = '187989840'; // departmentId
            tracker.set('dimension1', dimensionValue);
            // ...

            tracker.send("pageview");

        });
```

Comment: I think I somewhat understand what you're saying. You say that if I name the tracker in create, it fails to set the custom dimensions here
````
tracker.set('dimension1', dimensionValue);
````

What I don't understand is your sample code. How is your sample code different from what I have above? Also, I have multiple tracking IDs I need to use for different reasons. My full code looks something like this. 

````
$(googleAnalyticsClientContainerArray).each(function (i, e) {
 ga("create", e.trackingID, { 'name': e.name });
})
````

how would it work for multiple tracking IDs?

Comment: you're using `ga('set', ...)` instead of `tracker.set( ..)`. If you're using named trackers, you'll have to  use altered format for `ga` call https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#using_a_named_tracker

Comment: that clears it up and it looks like it's working. thanks